# Change font of task editor window in Visual Studio 2019 SSIS package designer

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

In Visual studio 2019, I am using the SQL Server Integration Services extension to create SSIS packages. I cannot find a way in Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors to change the font for the task text editor windows. (See image showing the editor windows I am referring to.) I'd like to change the font to a fixed width font, like Consolas, but I cannot find a way to do that. Creating SQL queries, etc. with a font like Tahoma is maddening. Does anyone know how to change the font?

[Image showing text editor window in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ66i.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been an issue as long as SSIS has existed, and probably even the DTS days. It's maddening because it's so obviously wrong, but I get the sense that Microsoft simply doesn't care. SSDT has been on life-support for years.

tl;dr: you can't.